# How to secure a public facing WCF service hosted on IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5, security, wcf-security

I have been writing WCF services for internal use for quite a while (alongside WinForms and MVC web apps).  However, I now need to expose one of the services to the great unwashed!

Since this is from a single source company I proposed the following:

**Architecture**

- Company uses VPN to send request to our DMZ server over HTTPS/SSL

  - DMZ firewall only allows specific Company IP
- DMZ IIS server passes request to our internal IIS server

  - Internal firewall only allows DMZ server INTERNAL FACING IP
- Internal IIS WCF service consumes request and sends response back up the chain.

However, my IT manager wants more than this and more...in detail.

e.g.

- What accounts to use or create, and what permissions to give them.
- How to limit public facing IIS server from being DoS'd, hacked, etc.
- How to stop public facing IIS server displaying "secure" details accidentally

  - What to turn off inside server/IIS
  - What files to restrict access to e.g. trace.axd

I can understand his reasons too - if it all goes ttsup, then he carries the can...whcih means ultimately I carry the can!  From a background in mainframe and IBM/Websphere, all he hears about is how IIS is "not secure".

I suspect that what he *really* hears is "devs/admins are not securing IIS/WCF properly"...so I want to try to do it "properly" !

*(for info, I am going through [Troy Hunt's posts](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/07/lessons-in-website-security-anti.html)...but there's a lot in here!  I've tried going through MSDN's reams of "kids drawing paper" and find oit very hard ot extract what I need to know from the endless "lets make this paragraph longer and sounds more important while hiding the salient facts" filler in there!)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server and IIS are secure.  However, if you're going to use this for say credit card transactions or other items that you don't wan't fall into the wrong hands, then you'll need to secure the server further than the out of the box settings.

This is a guide I used to hammer down a Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS 7.5 (patched to current standards) recently.  You don't have to use them all but it will help to secure the server at an extremely granular level.  Also, the IIS link below is for 7.0 but it applies to 7.5 as well.

Windows Server 2008 r2

http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/ncp/repository/checklistDetail?id=377

IIS

http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/ncp/repository/checklistDetail?id=400

It will take some time to go through as you will soon see but you be able to show what needs to be done to secure the server and product from the out of the box settings.  You will also be able to draw up a document to give to your boss in what is going to be needed to secure your server.

Comment: Thank you :) ... er...what do I actually follow to secure the server? lol.  I know it is on there somewhere, but not sure what I am looking at/for!

Comment: Click the Member Server Link at the top left (the other is for a Domain Controller) it's titled 'Windows 2008 R2 MS STIG Benchmark Version 1, Release 5' and 'Download Standalone XCCDF - IIS 7.0 STIG Version 1, Release 1' for IIS.  Open the Zip file after download and you'll have a bunch of PDF files to browse through that will set you in the right direction.  If you look through their site they have other documents for other potential work related devices.  Good Luck!